# Loading multiple images to jsp from DB

Tags: jsp, servlets, websphere, blob

I am retrieving multiple images from database (blob) and loading it to jsp using `<img src="www.xyz.com?img=123">`.

All 'src' of `<img>` go to servlet and get the blob image and is outputted using `response.getOutputStream().write()`. Since there are some 8 to 10 images, the websphere server crashes.

Any idea?

Can we store these images (after getting from DB) in some temporary folder and the configure the temporary path in server and load these images using `<img>`?

Comment: Does it work if you only have one image?

Comment: As Michael suggested, what is the behaviour when you have only 1 or 2 images. Does the server crash with a OOM error? If not what is the error?

Comment: If there are only one or two images, then images get loaded perfectly.

Comment: What is the reason for server crash? Is that an OOM? How big are the images? What happens if you choose two images that are very big? WHat is the outcome?

Answer (score 1):

That's look very strange if your application server crashes. Check if you close database connection, and streams like response.getOutputStream() . It's more than 10 times faster if you store images in folder, let say, configure img folder in web server like Apache, and write image to /img/image_id

Comment: Yeah, i am closing database and stream connection. Thank you for the reply.